# Amcharts visualize portion of data in horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to visualize an horizontal bar chart and I want to show  just a portion of the loaded records and to be able to scroll the results.

I tried to perform this using a vertical scrollbar. This is the resulting JSFiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9k2481g/).

```
function loadBar(){ 

    // Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    // Create chart instance
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

    // Set up data source
    chart.data= [
    {"name": "Mario12","overhead": 2},
    {"name": "Jenny12","overhead": 2},
    ...
    ];


    //create category axis for years
    var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    var yTitle = 'Agents';
    categoryAxis.title.text = yTitle;
    ...

    //create value axis for income and expenses
    var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.min = 0;
    ...


    //create columns
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.categoryY = "name";
    series.dataFields.valueX = "overhead";
    ...

    chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
    chart.scrollbarY.parent = chart.leftAxesContainer;

}

loadBar();
```

The wanted result should be instead [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7f2b.png)